# Purpose of setting Class Property as virtual without any kind of interface?

Tags: c#

Recently I have switched the Job. Here I have gone through the code where I found the "virtual" keyword and I have confirmed that it is not part of any kind of inheritance. I tried to search on google but could not find the satisfactory answer. Below is the code for the reference:

```
public class Department
{
    public virtual int DepartmentId { get; private set; }

    public Department(int departmentId)
    {
        this.DepartmentId = departmentId;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain the use of virtual here?

Comment: As far as I can tell according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) this serves no purpose if the class is not extended.

Comment: Maybe that question is better aimed at the person who wrote that code... Maybe it's a residue of a former inheritance structure ... but who knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that *if* some future subclass `Foo : Department` wishes, it can override that property to change the behavior of the accessors. This seems an unlikely requirement, and you shouldn't make things `virtual` by default - polymorphism should be designed for and tested. In particular, calling a `virtual` member in a constructor is a bit dangerous, which is what the constructor would now do; in theory this means that you *could* end up with a scenario where the sub-class `override` on the setter gets invoked *before* the sub-class constructor has executed, which means the state may be indeterminate.